# How do you translate "Haz" from Spanish?

Tags: general-topology, translation-request, mathematical-spanish

Is anyone familiar with this term?

From [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teor%C3%ADa_de_haces):

> An **haz** $F$ over a topological space $X$ gives for each open subset $U\subseteq X$ a set $F(U)$ with a "richer" structure $[\cdots]$.
>
> **Haces** are used in topology, algebraic geometry and differencial geometry, whenever we want to retain the algebraic information that varies with each open set of the given geometrical object.

Keep in mind I translated those bits as correctly as I could.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it means 'sheaf'

Comment: Haz: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teor%C3%ADa_de_haces Sheaf: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics) Same thing.

Comment: It is a sheaf, and for future reference you can click "otras idiomas" on the left to view the page in other languages

Comment: @ElliotG Oh, I was not aware of that at all, thanks! Thank you Henry and enth.

Comment: It depends. Some people translate "haz" as "bundle" (in this case, "sheaf" is translated as "gavilla") and some people translate "haz" as "sheaf" and use "fibraci\'{o}n" for "bundle".

Comment: If fibracion is bundle then what is fibration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haz = Sheaf.

Fibrado = Bundle (as in “fibrado vectorial”, vector bundle).

YoTengoUnLCD = IHaveAnLCD.

Comment: As far as I know, “stalk“ is translated as “fibra”; for fibration, I think it's translated as “fibración”, but I'd have to check.